# OpenOpt KSP is not defined

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

I am trying to experiment with the OpenOpt package in Python to solve some multi-constaint knapsack problem but right now I am just trying to run the example from the OpenOpt site.

I believe I have everything installed properly because I can go into Python and import the individual modules such as OpenOpt, FuncDesigner, etc just fine.

When I try to run the KSP example I get an error saying the KSP is not defined but the OpenOpt module is being imported.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from openopt import *
from numpy import sin, cos
N = 150
items = [
    {
        'name': 'item %d' % i, # pay attention that Python indexation starts from zero
        'cost': 1.5*(cos(i)+1)**2,
        'volume': 2*sin(i) + 3,
        'mass': 4*cos(i)+5,
        'n':  1 if i < N/3 else 2 if i < 2*N/3 else 3 # number of elements
    }
    for i in range(N) # i = 0, ... , N-1
    ]

constraints = lambda values: (
                         values['volume'] < 10,
                         values['mass'] < 100,
                         values['nItems'] <= 10,
                         values['nItems'] >= 5
                         # we could use lambda-func, e,g.
                         # values['mass'] + 4*values['volume'] < 100
                         )
objective = 'cost'
p = KSP(objective, items, goal = 'max', constraints = constraints)
r = p.solve('glpk', iprint = 0)
print(r.xf)
```

Exact error:

```
File "test_knap.py", line 25, in <module>
p = KSP(objective, items, goal = 'max', constraints = constraints)
NameError: name 'KSP' is not defined
```

Comment: Is `KSP` included in `openopt.__all__`? If not, it won't be included when you do `from openopt import *`. You can solve this by importing it explicitly: `from openopt import KSP` or similar.

Comment: I tried that but now I get cannot import name KSP.  Odd that I have the openopt module but it doesn't appear to include KSP at all for some reason.